# New window without creating a new Screen object

Tags: interface

I work with dual monitors, but there are many reasons why I may end up with only one window open. For example, if I accept the save while closing Blender, it opens with only one.

Is there a way to open another window without creating a Screen datablock? For example, by opening an existing Screen in another window (rather than creating the unneeded Screen datablock)?

My current process is to Duplicate the existing Screen to a new window (Ctrl-Alt-W), then delete the Screen datablock it creates.

Comment: Leon: thank you for the edit. I rolled back the changes though, because I think your edit was not actually what I was trying to say. You may already know this, but a Screen is a datablock representing a UI layout. A window refers to a viewport, which a Screen can be opened into. Please let me know if I misunderstood/misunderstand something.

Comment: OK. I see. I just thought you are mentioning the word "sreen" as "monitor". Now I get it. Then, you may try dragging the little "triangle" on the upperright corner of a certain window while holding Shift. See if that's what you want.

Comment: When I do that, it creates an additional Screen datablock, for example "PortraitSculptingLayout.001" (or ".005" if I've done it a few times already). These accumulate in my Screen list.

Comment: The word "Screen" you mentioned now sounds like "Layout". Right? I personally prefer samblers answer.

Comment: Yes, Leon, I'm using multiple terms for it to attempt to clarify, but the Blender English docs call them "Screens". I agree, I like sambler's answer as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have two monitors but I only have one blender window open. I expand the window to fill both monitors and then alter the screen layouts so that there is a split on the edge of the physical monitors. By setting the window size then saving the startup file, it always opens to this size, and includes my layouts, I also disable Load UI so that I keep my layouts with other files.

[image]

You may notice that the two monitors are different resolutions, I have a python console filling the off-monitor part that is not visible.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean about the off-resolution? I run one in portrait mode so I can have more of the Outliner expanded when dealing with complex rigs. I'm thinking your suggestion, although good, doesn't help with that.

Comment: Actually, cancel that, I get it. Your method would work. Thank you.

Comment: Side note, there are added benefits to your method. Previously, it's been a pain selecting an item in the Outliner and then trying to perform an action on it, which gets very squirrelly about which 3D viewport is in the same window, etc. etc. Your method will also be nicer when I want to take a little space back for another app or to watch the news while I work. Lastly, your method will let me switch the screen layout for everything at once. I never switch major operations (e.g. animation vs. UV editing) on one display while leaving another (e.g. sculpting) on the other.

Comment: e.g., your approach addresses this problem: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/how-to-focus-on-different-windows-across-multi-monitors-to-hit-a-hotkey?rq=1