# Have second window with different perspective open only when a second monitor is connected?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, 3d-view, windows

I have Blender on my laptop,  into which I sometimes plug an external monitor, and set up some different regions to make my workflow smoother/easier.

When I save and close my project, the multiple windows are saved as expected.  However the next time I open Blender, I might not have my second monitor connected, and both windows will be forced onto one display.  **Is there a way to detect if my second monitor is connected when I open a project, and automatically get rid of the extra window when it is not?**

Comment: You might be able to use some kind of python script to do this

Comment: In python you might want to use `ctypes` and call system libraries to get information about the connected monitors. A quick search on google revealed an  example script to get the resolution of all connected monitors (and thus the monitor count) [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/460509-get-the-actual-and-usable-sizes-of-all-the-monitor/). In linux you will probably have to call some X11 library instead of the user32.dll

Comment: [this might interest you](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21560/935)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you create 2 different screen layouts? one for single monitor and another for duo monitor?

That way you'll have them both saved and you can switch between the 2 and then all you'd have to do is stretch blender to fit duo monitors.