# Blender efficient dual monitor setup

Tags: interface

I use dual monitor setup with diffrent screen layouts. So I have a "Default_l" screen layout and a "Default_r" screen layout. Is there a way to automate the change of the screen layout:
When I change one screen layout for example from "Default_l" to "Compositing_l" the other screen layout also changes from Default_r to "Compositing_r"?

Comment: i don't know enough about how the layouts are stored internally but you could probably wright a python script that takes the value of one screens layout as input and then changes the other one based on that.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21564/935) interesting.

Answer (score 8):

Duplicate the window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>) for the second monitor, then you can change the layout individually.
I recommend to change the mouse behaviour by OS to automatically focus window on hovering, otherwise you have to click to activate the alternate window.

Comment: That's exactly the thing that's bugging me: clicking to activate the other window gets tedious and cumbersome. Is this a setting that's changed on Blender settings, or Windows 10 control panel?

Comment: https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to work with two (or more) monitors:

- **With one window spanned across multiple monitors**.

  On this setup both monitors can be controlled by a single layout: changing layout would affect the content of all screens. You can easily achieve what you are after this way.
- **Different windows, one for each monitor.**

  On this modality the layouts are independent. Changing the layout on one window will not affect the other.

  Maybe some clever coder can make a plugin to do what you are asking for the two windows mode...

Answer (score 1):

On Blender 2.81, go to Window -> New Window. This will create a new Window for the same workspace. You can then customize the layout of the new window.

It's properly reacting to mouse hover. But I think it's not detecting the Shift/Ctrl key before you give the focus to that window. So if you want to scroll or zoom you have to give the other window the focus before you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think there is a way to do that. I was under the impression that multiple window screen layouts were created automatically for each independent window and used "internally", not meant to be switched manually or independently by the user I believe. Not sure though maybe someone else can answer better.

Only way I can think of to achieve your desired behavior is setting up different screen layouts (each with its own left and right sub-layouts) for compositing on the left, and for compositing on the right. This will sadly result in double the amount of screen layouts, with some not meant to be used directly. That is how I have it setup at least.

Comment: I have the same setup. I would like to automate the process of switching between screen layouts, switch both layouts at once.

Answer (score 0):

just press SHIFT and just click or slightly drag in the right corner or your window,

[image]

it will pop it up as duplicate view as new application view.

[image]

Just drag it on wherever you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows focus on Hover
To enable the Xmouse window tracking in Windows 10, do the following.

1. Open the classic Control Panel.
2. Go to Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center.
3. On the right, find and click the link *Make the mouse easier to use*.
4. Check the option *Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse* and click *OK*.

Comment: I originally liked this answer, then I tried it out, and found that 1) it really interfered with other use, making it impossible to use a text editor on top of a maximized window to write and read at the same time; 2) it didn't even do what I wanted with split Blender windows, which is for kb shortcuts to apply to the window over which my mouse hovers.  Instead, something about Blender, possibly the fact that it's a single app with two windows, made the shortcuts apply in the most previously clicked window instead.