# Using 2 monitors on Mac pro

Tags: interface

I'm new to Blender and i'm using 2 monitors on a Mac pro,osX El capitan, I created a second window but it seems that Blender only recognize 1 monitor...
Is there a way to change this behaviour ?

Thanks by adance

Regards

Paul

Comment: What happens when you drag the second window to your other monitor?  Is it just blocked?

Comment: What do you mean "Blender only recognize 1 monitor" what happens when you drag the window to the second monitor?

Comment: [This may interest you](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21564/935)

Comment: Hi guys,Thanks for your answer ! What I meant is : when I reopen Blender the 2 windows are on the same monitor and I have to move 1 by hand everytime on the other monitor...

Answer (score 2):

Shift right click on the upper left corner of a window creates a floating window. Now you can drag that over to the second monitor.[image]

Comment: Thanks Critch ! but I already created a second window by clicking on ''window'' and then moved it on second monitor, it works fine ! but when I close and reopen Blender the windows are on the same screen and I have to move one manually everytime...